# Get value of the highlighted item in a combobox dropdown list? Excel VBA

Tags: excel, combobox

The mouseover event of a combobox on my form triggers a label to become visible and show details of the currently selected combobox value. When the user clicks the down arrow to show the combobox list items available for selection, I want the label to update with details of the currently highlighted item in the dropdownlist without having to actually select it as the combobox value.

In other words, as the user moves the mouse over the items and the highlighted item changes, I want the details in the label to update for the highlighted value.

So far, I have found nothing on how to do this. Excel obviously knows which item is highlighted, but how to access this information programmatically eludes me.

Any ideas?

Comment: is this combobox a control or the list generated from Data Validation?

Answer (score 0):

If the combobox is a control then you could use the MouseMove event to get the current highlighted item.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If ComboBox1.TopIndex > -1 Then
        Dim curIndex As Integer
        curIndex = ComboBox1.TopIndex + Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Y / 13.5, 0)
        curValue = ComboBox1.List(curIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

then show the tooltip.
Note: 13.5 is, by my tests, the height of an item in dropdown...

Comment: I posted 'mouseover' in my question, but I meant to say 'Mousemove'. I'm using the mousemove event for this already. Once the event triggers, I can pull the selected value using .value, use it to populate a label, and then make the label visible. But .value always stays the same as the highlighted value in the dropdown changes. Is there a way to point to the value of the highlighted list item without actually clicking and selecting and setting the combobox value?

Comment: Brilliant. I had begun coding something like this but nowhere near as elegant. Thanks